# Text view doesn't show any text

Tags: android, textview

I am new to java and andriod and i think that i did something wrong with thread
Program starts without any errors.

I have inserted one button just for test and it shows without problem. Text view doesnt even displays "Hello world" default string.

Here is the code

```
    package com.example.studentservis;

    import android.R.string;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.io.*;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

        StringHandler stringHandler = new StringHandler();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

            thread.run();

            TextView txtView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            txtView.setText(stringHandler.getString());

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);


            return true;
        }

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {

                    stringHandler.setString(webRequest());


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    stringHandler.setString(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };


        public String webRequest() throws Exception{
            String servisURL = "http://www.sczg.unizg.hr/student-servis/";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(servisURL).get();
            Elements jobNode = doc.select("div.jobBox");

            return jobNode.get(0).text();
        }

        public class StringHandler
        {
            public String str = "test";

            public void setString(String s)
            {
                str = s;
            }

            public String getString()
            {
                return str;
            }
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a handler or a asyctask for this purpose. Asynctask is easier.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can create your own thread but remember to update ui on the ui thread.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
    android:text="Loading..." />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

Removed StringHandler cause i felt it was unnecessary in this context.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

 TextView txtView ;
 String s;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    txtView  = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1); // initialize textview
    //txtView.setText(stringHandler.getString());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {  // thread
        @Override  
        public void run(){

            try {
                s = webRequest(); // get string 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui threa
            {
               public void run() 
               { 
                    txtView.setText(s); // update ui on the ui thread.
               } 
            });


        }
}).start();


}

public String webRequest() throws Exception{   // web request
    String servisURL = "http://www.sczg.unizg.hr/student-servis/";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(servisURL).get();
    Elements jobNode = doc.select("div.jobBox");

    return jobNode.get(0).text();
}
}
```

Resulting snap shot

[image]

Comment: He is not updating the UI thread from another thread. He updated the UI from UI thread. That is not the problem. The problem is that when he wants to update the UI the new Thread hasn't finished yet and doesn't have data ready

Comment: @MiroMarkarian agreed i updated my answer  if you have downvoted you can remove the same now

Comment: Ok. But anyway it is the same as my answer :)

Comment: @MiroMarkarian that's why i upvoted your answer in the first place coz you pointed the mistake first. second i din't copy paste from your answer. you can initialize textview in onCreate() no need to do that in the runonuithread. just a suggestion

Comment: You've forgotten to Override the function in your answer. Does it work?

Comment: Thanks, it works! :D i didnt put thread in onCreate before, i thought that i needs to be in class like other functions.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian you can put override. Yup it works and i posted the snap shot after testing

Comment: @Raghunandan the run function in the Runnable. However if it works. then it's fine :)

Comment: @MiroMarkarian its good you pointed that out. its better have that annotation i edited the same.

Comment: Give some upvotes for this guy! :D Thanks for detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

When you start a new Thread, the UI thread won't wait until the new thread is complete. That is the purpose of the Threads.

Here :

```
thread.run();
```

When you a start the new thread to update the `stringHandler`, the UI thread tries to process the next command which is :

```
txtView.setText(stringHandler.getString());
```

When the UI thread gets to this, the `stringHandler` hasn't updated yet, so It's null and thus it will show nothing in the textview.

All you should do is to try to update the textview from the new Thread when it's finished.

Try this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try {

            stringHandler.setString(webRequest());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            stringHandler.setString(e.getMessage());
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView txtView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                txtView.setText(stringHandler.getString());
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Could i just add `thread.join();` after `stringHandler.setString(webRequest());` ? Join stops thread, right?

Comment: Join pauses current thread and waits for another thread to finish. that is not simply a good idea. because that makes your UI unresponsive (= Application hangs, won't response to user interactions ). I would not recommend that

Comment: If you really want to use it that should be after `thread.start()` not after `stringHandler.setString(webRequest());`

Comment: I dont know how to implement any of code from these answers. Im getting several errors from each suggestion.
And yea, thread.join() doesnt work...i dont know what to do

Comment: Just copy the thread code from my answer to your code and replace the thread you have. and that will work.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code : `txtView.setText(stringHandler.getString());`

should be put after the thread finished.

```
        thread.run(); <------ Start running thread in background

        TextView txtView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtView.setText(stringHandler.getString());
        // the textView was set without knowing whether the Thread is finished or not.
        // thus, textView is shown as empty, because stringHandler.getString() still has empty string
```

My suggestion is that you implement it inside an `asyncTask`, so that you can set the text within `onPostExecute()`

Good luck ^^

**EDIT :** 
here's some example AsyncTask

```
private class StringSet extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void> {

@Override 
protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
         stringHandler.setString(webRequest());
    } catch (Exception e) {
         stringHandler.setString(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void... results) {
    txtView.setText(stringHandler.getString());
    }
}
```

And replace your `thread.run()` with `new StringSet().execute();`

Comment: i dont know how to implement your code. Im getting errors on `protected void doInBackground(Void... params)` and `protected void onPostExecute(Void... results)`

Comment: You edited the code on eclipse IDE, right?, then all you need is write the `private class StringSet extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void> { }`, and let Eclipse handle the method implementation for you

Try pressing Alt+Shift+S inside the `asyncTask` class, and select `Override/Implement methods`, select `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` you should be able to do it ^^